# Can we please get The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List question unlocked again?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, locked-questions

*To set the scene:*
In the recent Great Question Deletion Audit of 2012, **[this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122205/133368)** — explaining why it's not in Stack Overflow's interest to delete **[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/140719)** —, despite only referring to a single item on that list, became the top-voted answer. As some helpful commenter found out, [there are **hundreds of links** to this question on Stack Exchange alone, and **thousands of links** out on the Internet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122120/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2012/122205#comment328025_122205).

*What I've been doing:* 
Seeing the reason in some of the critique on that question (like most of the answers not making much sense), I went through the answers over the weekend, trying to find duplicated and low-quality answers, commenting on almost all the low-scored questions plus a few higher ones, downvoting bad ones to encourage the answerers to delete them, and also lobbied for help in the C++ chat room in order to get them under the score threshold that allows us to delete them anyway. I also flagged three or four answers which  were plain dupes.

*What came out of it:*
Now a mod went through those flags, and validated them all (thanks for doing the work!). However, he did not delete any of the flagged answers. What's worse, he **locked the question**. Now those I have commented on cannot reply to my comment. The C++ community cannot vote on the answers anymore, cannot delete duplicated answers ourselves, and cannot even edit the question.

*What this means:*
This is of course nonsense, since this list needs to be updated once in a while. Especially with the new C++ standard being published last year, and publications only slowly catching up, it's vital for this question to be editable. (In fact, Jerry just added a link regarding this only five days ago.)

*What I want:*
Could some mod please again **unlock this question**?

Comment: Ugh. Annoying. Certainly one of the most useful C++ answers, and generally C++ resources, on the web.

Comment: sbi, I changed the title to match what I believe you're asking for. Since I actually *inverted* the meaning, please check.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I edited it, too. I can't make head nor tail from the history, but now it's correct. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: It's been an *hour*, and you already need it unlocked again?  How often do you guys update this thing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The link to downvote/delete some of the bad answers is sitting on the starboard in the C++ chat, so everyone who comes in is taking a peek.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: As I wrote, the cleanup was in progress. It's now halted.

Comment: Can I get a list of the answers you want deleted?  If you flag them again, they're just going to get lost in the sea of flags that is the flag queue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: For one: If a question is locked, we mere humans cannot edit, vote flag, or do anything useful with that the question or any of the answers. But also: I don't want to push my views about what's delete-worthy on the community (well, except for the dupes, of course), and I'd rather let them vote on their own. If an answer has accumulated enough downvotes, we can delete it ourselves — if there's enough of us to agree that it should be deleted.

Comment: Well, I deleted all of the answers with zero and negative votes. I trust the C++ community won't miss those too much.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks, those are probably fine. I have some answers that I consider bad that have several dozen upvotes, though, and I wouldn't want to do this on my own. Those I had flagged are now all deleted. Thanks for your help and for unlocking the question!

Comment: @sbi thanks for the new display name

Comment: @Some: It took me 5mins to figure out your comment. I very much hope you weren't offended by me not digging out your name. If you were, I very sincerely apologize.

Comment: @sbi oh please no worries. I just thought it would be funny for whomever follows the link and I wanted to clue you in to my lame joke.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter, even completely independent of the joke, that's actually a pretty damn good display name, especially if you comment a lot.

Comment: @Some Lol, you still have that almost a year and a half later :P

Comment: @Doorknob: Double that. `:-)`