# What happened with "Search in list of favorited questions?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality)

Does anyone know the story of [Search in favorited questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions). I want to know why it Jeff Atwood♦ tagged it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and one year later changed it to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

Was this feature implemented and then removed?

Comment: It got broken see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78946/148672

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I would accept that comment if I could, consider turning it into an answer :D

Comment: Well if it were posted as an answer that would seem to be #6 on [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/148672) and the corrective action is vote to close...

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter in the hypothetical case that you were named "Some Helpful Answerer", would you still have chosen to post as comment instead of an answer?

Comment: I suppose so. As an aside I adopted the name when [sbi referred to me that way in a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129443/can-we-please-get-the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list-question-unlocked-agai#comment354176_129443) it use to be the same as my SO display name