# Disallow homework tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, homework, tags

The [homework tag is officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) for a while now. Yet still, there is hardly a day without new questions tagged as [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).

While this makes for easy game when one still tries to obtain the Copy Editor badge, shouldn't the tag rather be rejected for new questions?

The rejection note could contain a link to [this community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/154351) on homework questions.

Comment: I thought that the cleanup effort on questions that were tagged as such was still ongoing, so a "nuke and pave" wouldn't be in the best interests right this moment.  Banning the tag would also mean removing it from the other questions, which might not be desirable.

Comment: It's not that much about *banning* the tag, actually. I thought of a note explaining why this tag cannot be used anymore. Clearly, no one is reading the tag's excerpt...

Comment: It shouldn't make easy game for the copy editor badge though. Users should retag the question if they have that privilege if removal of the tag is the only change that needs to be made. If the edit makes other improvements, then what's wrong with that? Not exactly gaming the badge.

Comment: Hmm, I might have closed too quickly here, sorry about that.  I think we know what the issue is, but I think we also need a generalized feature request to disallow new tag usage, etc.

Comment: This request is similar, but didn't gain a lot of traction: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172541/blacklist-the-books-tag

Comment: Isn't that what the ability to lock tags is @casper? (in the possible dupe)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I suppose so.  I wish we had that right about now.