# Do not delete questions that have answers

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions, undelete-request

I herewith object to the deletion of ***[Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131218/ivor-hortons-beginning-visual-c-2010/3131316#3131316)***. No, it's not an exemplary question, and, yes, I agree to it being *closed*. I object to it being *deleted*, though. Can some mod please undelete it?

Rationale: When the question is closed, rather than deleted, it can still be found, and answers read, by non-10k users and occasional visitors. At the same time, everybody seeing the question notice that it got closed and for what reason, and has thus a chance to learn that this kind of questions is not wanted.

If the question is deleted, those googling for it will not find it at Stackoverflow and might ask it again.

Comment: If an off-topic question is found, it can be used by others as "evidence" that such posts are allowed.

Comment: @Oded Isn't it closed as off-topic?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - Yes, but it is _still there_. New users don't notice, or choose to ignore such subtleties.

Comment: @Oded: If you can't even take the fews secs to read my rationale, why bother commenting? If a question is found to be "closed as not constructive", this can be used by others as evidence that such posts are not wanted. If they are deleted, they can't.

Comment: Can you (or someone else) provide screen shot of the QnA in question.

Comment: @Oded if they don't notice it, maybe *that's* the real problem? Not that I would be a fan of gigantic "CLOSED" in red stamped all over the question, but if that's necessary... And if someone ignores that, I doubt he will be a welcomed person in our community; after all, we don't want people that don't read such statements, do we?

Comment: The whole point of closing a question is to make it a candidate for deletion - as a question that is not suitable to [SO]. If we keep these around for eternity, why close them at all?

Comment: This essentially reads to me as - why did you delete this useful resource? Even though it is off-topic and doesn't belong on the site?

Comment: Last I checked, a deleted question is not expunged from the records for ever more, it is simply hidden from those with less than 10K rep

Comment: The whole point of StackExchange / StackOverflow is to be a repository of useful questions. If OT questions still stick around but closed then that means SE / SO becomes a collection of very useful questions and off-topic closed questions. That's not really of much use to people if they have to wade through loads of 'Closed' posts to find some useful open ones.

Comment: @Oded I was under impression closing is to a) preserve duplicates with valuable information b) make offtopic or otherwise not-belonging questions stand as an example what NOT to post. And I think it's pretty much aligned with the SO policy.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz - With "asked 2 years ago, viewed 642 times", it doesn't count in my eyes as a valuable post to preserve (not for historical reasons, anyway). It was not a duplicate - it was simply "not constructive" and it took a while to remove. As for B, there are plenty of such posts around.

Comment: "If the question is deleted, those googling for it will not find it at Stackoverflow and might ask it again." Yeah, not falling for that one, sorry.

Comment: @casperOne: Thank you for taking the time to post such a convincing rationale. Having your reasoning explained to me in such detail will certainly help me to understand your POV.

Comment: @Oded: _"The whole point of closing a question is to make it a candidate for deletion"_. Nope, you're wrong there. And why to keep them around I have now spelled out in the question, and — especially for you — again in a comment. Again, if you can't be bothered to read an argument and afford the necessary effort to understand it, then please don't bother commenting on my questions.

Comment: OK. I'll bite. What is the point then?

Comment: @sbi The part I quoted is a bait from you and we both know it.  I didn't think that you needed that explained to you.  Your position is basically "let's keep *every* crappy question undeleted because someone *else* might ask it."  If that's the case, I'm going to start going through the deleted [tag:c++] posts and undeleting them, because we don't want someone else to ask those crappy questions again.

Comment: @Oded: _"This essentially reads to me as - why did you delete this useful resource?"_ Yeah, we all noted that. It's not what I wrote, though. So would you please go back and read what I actually wrote? Thanks. HAND.

Comment: That question was abysmally bad, and the very definition of a "broken window".  It needed to go.

Comment: @casparOne: You know, that is a convincing argument for you doing so.

Comment: @sib Ninja @ comments for the win.

Comment: If anyone of you should use the "broken window" analogy again I shall scream at my co-workers at the top of my lungs. Hell, as long as _there's a link to_ ___this madhouse named meta___ _on SO_, anyone being concerned about "broken windows" is just a hypocrite.

Comment: Start screaming.

Comment: I agree, we are hypocrites when we say "broken windows" because the biggest one of all, the C++ book list, is undeleted and open. [Mic drop](http://checktheblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/drop-the-mic.jpeg)

Comment: You know, @casperOne, this is exactly the attitude that makes meta the worst broken window at SO.

Comment: @Bart: They weren't impressed.

Comment: Two years old, viewed 666 times ([no, really](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r8mj2.png)).  Not exactly a candidate for hanging onto this one.  Of course, you can get the lounge in action to undelete.  Or roll the content into the main C++ book question...

Answer (score 10):

This is a poor question. Its text:

> How good this book is for learning C++? Has someone read it?

the most upvoted answer:

> Without knowing the book, I would strongly suspect from the title that it teaches you "Visual C++" instead of C++. That is, it will likely teach you how the IDE works, the VC dialect of C++, and C++/CLI.
>   So if you want to learn ***C++***, you'd better have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).
>
> However, if you indeed want to learn ***Visual C++***, I'll step aside for someone who actually knows the book.

It's basically a plug for another question (which probably shouldn't around either, but [there be dragons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144359/why-is-the-definitive-c-book-list-question-allowed-but-other-book-recommend)).

*If* this was a useful question, I'd consider undeleting it, but as it stands, I have to agree with the moderator who deleted the question. It's doing no good staying around, and we are not worse off for deleting it.

If there is a closed question with:

- A lot of views *and*
- A lot of external links *and*
- Good content *and*
- Makes Stack Overflow worse off for deleting it,

*then* it shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Shame; now we can't delete *this* question because you answered!

Comment: @ScottW **Maniacal Laugh**.

Comment: This is a well-researched list of reasons to close the question. I was, however, objecting to it being _deleted_.

Comment: @sbi See the criteria I listed for something to not be deleted. Which of those criteria does it meet? If it doesn't meet *all* of them, it should be deleted.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: A question that meets those criteria shouldn't be _closed_.

Comment: @sbi Now we just disagree. By the way, [What's your best programmer joke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

Comment: reaction: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻