# Why is the node.js resource recommendation question allowed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, locked-questions

[How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

> ### locked by Shog9♦ Jul 19 at 22:30
>
> This question's answer is a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here*

I'm sure the answers to this question are useful, but why is this particular one allowed when we generally disallow resource recommendation questions?
Even though you can't add new answers, the existing answers can still be edited and people are making edits quite frequently.

Comment: Which is why it is locked. Some communities have shown that they are willing to take on the work to keep a question like this up to date, there is a similar exception for some C++ questions.

Comment: Particularly, [Shog's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144363) applies here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Dupe indeed, thanks for the info.