# How come some subjective questions are allowed and not only that, rampantly upvoted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I once posted a question on Stack Overflow asking if learning Haskell would help me learn node.js. The question was downvoted into double digits and shut down in 5 minutes flat.

Imagine my confusion when I saw this question, "How do I get started with Node.js" asking

> "Are there any good resources to get started with Node.JS? Any good
>   tutorials, blogs or books?"

which has 1268 upvotes?

[How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

Comment: Note that the example you gave was asked 4 years ago. A lot changed in what is or isn't good for the site since then.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't always a good example of its own guidelines. I agree that the question should be officially closed though.

Comment: Things kept for historic reasons (meaning lots of incoming links) are not a good indicator for the on-topicness of gimme-tutorial questions. Your example list ought to be part of the tag-wiki meanwhile. But it's community wiki already, so.

Comment: Irrationality is the square root of all evil.

Comment: Using a question that is exactly 4 years old today doesn't make for a good example, especially when it has been turned into a form of wiki. If you did a question/answer combo as thorough as that it probably would have been well received.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This lock notice is partly misleading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading)

Comment: You see here -11  thus far down votes for just asking about our (community) opinion
on a question. 
For me the problem is with some users culture (down vote first 
then think). Some users also think that down voting will bring 
the world closer to their ego.  As a professional instructor I never down vote .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because that isn't a question anymore. Not as we normally think of questions here on Stack Overflow: problem statements, with specific answers written by individuals, ranked according to votes received.

I could give you a long explanation for why that is, why we kept that "question" around when so many similar questions were removed... But it's easier to just show you.

[This is what that question looked like a few weeks after it was asked](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328231742/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-nodejs). Three answers, none of them much longer than a sentence, one consisting of a now-broken link and another of someone's idle opinion on how Node should be learned. A pretty poor showing indeed - I would challenge anyone to defend a question like that as particularly useful. But such questions - resource-requests - were fairly common for the time; we were still figuring out what worked and what did not.

[Eight months later, the situation wasn't much different](https://web.archive.org/web/20101125040003/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-nodejs). Oh, there were a few more answers, and a lot more views... But not much in the way of votes for all those views. Some links were already broken. Clearly, this - like so many other such questions - was not working.

Then, over a year after the question was first asked... [Something happened](https://web.archive.org/web/20111103081147/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-nodejs). Instead of dropping another answer with another link onto the page, someone had the idea of trying to *organize* the various resources they'd found useful, cataloging them in a single answer. Others [joined in](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5511507/revisions?page=2), adding and categorizing. And readers found *this* useful.

At this point, it stopped being a normal question. What grew up then and exists today is essentially a wiki, a collaboratively-edited compendium of information on a given topic.

We didn't really plan this. It's one of those things that happens sometimes when folks see a need and use the tools available to them to address it. Since it happened, and continues to be maintained, we allow it.

#### See also: [Why is "The Definitive C++ Book List" question allowed, but other book recommendation questions are not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144359/why-is-the-definitive-c-book-list-question-allowed-but-other-book-recommend)

Comment: Is the "collaborative effort" lock an alternative to the historical lock? Are there specific guidelines for getting it applied to a resources question?q

Comment: If it's a question with actively-maintained wiki answer(s) and generally doesn't fit with the normal Q&A model here, it's a good candidate for this. Historical Lock is a better choice for things that aren't appropriate but are seen as useful to keep around for reference - that is, things that are part of the historical record but shouldn't need to be changed.